# Flutter pause Timer when on screen. Stop when I jump to another screen. Resume when I get back on that screen

Tags: flutter, dart, timer

I have two pages in flutter app. Even when i move to secondpage (using navigator.push), the timer still runs in background. ( I know it because i am printing it in terminal also). Also, I already tried canceling my Timer in dispose method. it does not work. Also, If I use `navigator.pushReplacement`, it solves the problem of Timer being run in background, but i wont be able to go back to this page.

here is my full code:

```
    import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_2_practice/controller/controller_file.dart';
import 'new_screen.dart';

class MyHomePageUI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePageUI> createState() => _MyHomePageUIState();
}

class _MyHomePageUIState extends State<MyHomePageUI> {

  Timer? timer ;
  String abc ='df-1'; //default value: 'df-1'

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      if(mounted){
        setState( () {
          abc = DateFormat('hh:mm:ss a').format(DateTime.now());
        } );
      }
      print(abc);
    });
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
  print('test \n if you are seeing this, maybe you used Navigator.pushReplacement()');
  timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[900],
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          dispose();
          // Provider . of <MyController> (context, listen: false)  . addItemInList();
           Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()));


          /*MyController con = MyController();
          con.addItemInList();*/
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add,  color: Colors.white),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),


      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height:100,),
          Text(abc, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white70),),
          Text('current time', style: TextStyle(  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.white),),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dispose` method is only called once the page is finished and ready to be removed from the `WidgetTree`, In the first case when you use `Navigator.push` to navigate to another page, It won't remove the previous page and `Navigator.pushReplacement` replaces the first page and removes it from widget tree thus calls the `dispose` method.

So, to pause and resume after coming back to the first page, then you need to cancel timer before the `navigator.push` and `await` till it completes and resume after async is done

```
        void goToSecondpage () async {
              timer?.cancel();
              await Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondWidget()));
              initTimer();
            }
```

Full code [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=f6810e5d065d2c103d18579c655ddee8)

Comment: Thank you it was really useful. Also note that Timer should not declared as final.